# Thumbnails in media library not showing after upload path change

Tags: wordpress, upload, directory, media

After making these changes to change the folder for uploads I can no longer see thumbnails in my media library after uploading.

Could anyone suggest a fix?

Screenshot: http://take.ms/wtGMZ

Steps I took to do it: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-custom-upload-dir/

Comment: I do have a similar kind of problem. But I get the problem after changing the directory and the URL of the newly uploaded media seems to be repeated. Explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74663997/defining-new-directory-for-wordpress-image-library-gives-error-for-thumbnails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the below plugin to re-generate your site thumbnails, as Wordpress saves also the path in database:

[Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)

And also do check if you have given a permission to  `755`  if not do give your new upload folder a permission  `755`

Hope this helps you, anything else let me know.

Comment: Completely missed file permissions. Works perfectly now.

Thanks Repo!

Comment: I do have a similar kind of problem. But I get the problem after changing the directory and the URL of the newly uploaded media seems to be repeated. Explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74663997/defining-new-directory-for-wordpress-image-library-gives-error-for-thumbnails

Answer (score 0):

Check in Setting -> Media if Upload folder is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is happens when you move your site from one location to another.

Don't worry !

Do this >>

Login in admin >> In setting >> Media >>
/home/public_html/**hardwareithub.com**/wp-content/uploads >> modify it.

That's all done enjoy !